# Which one is correct removing elements from array or create new array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have to modify an array

Example

```
var full_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I have to remove `b` and `c` from the list

Which one is correct way. Either directly remove the elements or create a new array with the valid values from `full_list`?

Comment: the 'correct' way will depend on what you want to do next, are you ever going to use full_list again? (if yes then create a new modified copy, otherwise modify the one you have)

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your context, but mostly you'd better not create a new object, do this:

```
var full_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var removedparts = full_list.splice(1,2);
//full_list is ["a", "d"] and removedparts, as its name suggests: ["b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   var full_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

       full_list.splice(full_list.indexOf('b'),1);
       full_list.splice(full_list.indexOf('c'),1);
```